# Set custom attributes value as featured image in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For products, I have several custom attributes set up and among them is `images` which can have multiple images separated by `|`. You can have a look [Here](https://prnt.sc/jJwuhY1KQPBz). The products were inserted through woocommerce api. But the issues is the featured image which is responsible for showing the image in the frontend, isn't filled up. So I need to take the first image from the `images` attribute and set it as featured image. As they are already existing product so I tried to implement through the code below and added it in my `functions.php`. But it didn't work

```
function update_existing_products_featured_image() {

    $attribute_name = 'images';

    // Get all published simple products
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
    );

    $product_ids = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
        // Get the custom attribute value for the product
        $attribute_value = get_post_meta($product_id, '_' . $attribute_name, true);

        // Check if the attribute value contains '|' to separate images
        if ($attribute_value && strpos($attribute_value, '|') !== false) {
            // Explode the attribute value to get an array of image URLs
            $image_urls = explode('|', $attribute_value);

            // Get the first image URL from the array
            $first_image_url = trim($image_urls[0]);

            // Check if the first image URL is valid
            if (filter_var($first_image_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
                // Download the image and set it as the featured image
                $image_id = media_sideload_image($first_image_url, $product_id, '', 'id');
                set_post_thumbnail($product_id, $image_id);
            }
        }
    }
}


update_existing_products_featured_image();
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: the screenshot I provided have the values, you can check @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I solved it...posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

After much digging I solved it using `add_filter` hook in woocommerce

```
function set_custom_attribute_image_as_product_image($image, $product) {
    $images_attribute = $product->get_attribute('images');
    
    
    if (!empty($images_attribute)) {
         // Extract the first image link from the "images" attribute
         $images = explode('|', $images_attribute);
         $first_image = !empty($images[0]) ? $images[0] : '';

         if ($first_image) {
             // Replace the default product image with the first image from the attribute
             $image = '<img src="' . esc_url($first_image) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($product->get_name()) . '" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail">';
         }
     }

     return $image;
 }
 add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_image', 'set_custom_attribute_image_as_product_image', 10, 2);
```

Here I set the img src instead of setting it as a featured image...works fine for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

i work an similar solution...
if I find my solution, I will share it here with you.